# getRealPath between Tomcat6 and Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat8, tomcat6

In my web application, I have the following code:

```
    if( context == null )
        throw new WMSException( "Missing session context." );

    String path  = context.getRealPath("");
    if( path == null )
        throw new WMSException( "Missing context real path." );

    WebSocket ws    = new WebSocket();
    String    sep   = "/";
    int       where = path.lastIndexOf( sep );
    if( where < 0 ){
        sep   = "\\";
        where = path.lastIndexOf( sep );
    }

    path  = path.substring( 0, where );
    where = path.lastIndexOf( sep );
    path  = path.substring( 0, where ) + "/conf/wms";
    if( firstTime ){
        firstTime = false;
        System.out.println( "Getting configuration from " + path );
    }

    File      docFile = new File(path, "socket.xml");
    System.out.println( "Name " + docFile.getName() );
    System.out.println( "Path " + docFile.getPath() );
```

In tomcat 6, because of how getRealPath seems to work, I get the following:

```
/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/wms/socket.xml
```

In tomcat 8, I get the following, for the same war file:

```
/opt/tomcat8/webapps/conf/wms/socket.xml
```

Why the difference in how getRealPath works and how do I fix?

Comment: GetRealPath is supposed to get the path to something in your webapp. The Tomcat6 version wasn't doing that, it was returning the path to something in your Tomcat installation. So they fixed the bug in Tomcat 8.

Comment: `getRealPath` is for getting the path to a file inside the war file, i.e. to a staging area where Tomcat has extracted the file. It is entirely undocumented where that location is, and you should never use that path for accessing files outside the war file content. You need to fix your code, so it can be told through other means where to find external files.

Comment: Then what do I call instead of getRealPath that does the same thing Tomcat6 did with getRealPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was solved by noting that Tomcat6 did not put a "/" at the end but Tomcat8 does.  So my new code fixes it:
        LOGGER.info( "Get socket for client: " + client );

```
    if( context == null )
        throw new WMSException( "Missing session context." );

    String path  = context.getRealPath("");
    if( path == null )
        throw new WMSException( "Missing context real path." );

    LOGGER.info( "Path 1 '" + path + "'");

    WebSocket ws    = new WebSocket();
    String    sep   = "/";
    int       where = path.lastIndexOf( sep );
    if( where < 0 ){
        sep   = "\\";
        where = path.lastIndexOf( sep );
    }

    String newPath  = path.substring( 0, where );
    if( newPath.equals(path.substring(0, path.length() - 1 )))
    {
        where = newPath.lastIndexOf( sep );
        path  = newPath.substring( 0, where );
        LOGGER.info( "Path 2a '" + path + "'");
    }
    else
        path = newPath;

    LOGGER.info( "Path 2 '" + path + "'");
    where = path.lastIndexOf( sep );
    path  = path.substring( 0, where ) + "/conf/wms";
    LOGGER.info( "Path 3 '" + path + "'");
    if( firstTime ){
        firstTime = false;
        LOGGER.info( "Getting configuration from " + path );
    }

    LOGGER.info( "Path 4 '" + path + "'");
    File      docFile = new File(path, "socket.xml");
    LOGGER.info( "Name '" + docFile.getName() + "';Path '" + docFile.getPath() + "'");
```

The key was the `if( newPath.equals(path.substring(0, path.length() - 1 )))` if section.  Obviously, it could be solved in other ways.  Also, this issue is implied in quite a few places online, I just missed the connection with regards to "/" at the end of the path, so it could not up the directory tree correctly.

There was no easy way to get the tomcat home directory ( where we have "conf" directory ), so this was how we did it.  Not wishing to change things, just added that section of code to make it work.

There are other ways of solving it that I saw online.